# Factory Girl Polymorphic has_many, belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, factory-bot

```
class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :images, as: :imageable, foreign_key: :imageable_uuid, dependent: :destroy
end

class MenuPhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :image, as: :imageable, foreign_key: :imageable_uuid, dependent: :destroy
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :imageable, foreign_key: :imageable_uuid, :polymorphic => true
end
```

I have these models above use polymorphic. So in my factory girl i do it like this.

```
factory :food do
association :images, factory: :image
end

factory :menu_photo do
association :image, factory: :image
end

factory :image do
    photo { fixture_file_upload(Rails.root.join("spec", "fixtures", "pass.jpg"), "image/jpg") }
  end
```

When i test in rails console test environment with " FactoryGirl.create(:menu_photo) ", it works fine. it creates both :menu_photo and :image.
But when i run it with " FactoryGirl.create(:food) ", it errors with:
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for #

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're trying to set a single image for a has_many association.  What if you do something like this:

```
 factory :food do

    after(:create) { |f| 
       f.images.create!()
    }

 end
```

Comment: I think my code above should be working well, but it didn't. For me, i think this is one bug of FactoryGirl. And thx for ur answer, but it didn't work.